# Find ratio formed by the perpendicular bisector of an angle bisector

Tags: geometry, contest-math

Question: As shown in the figure, $AD$ is the angle bisector of $\triangle ABC$, the perpendicular bisector of $AD$ intersects the extension of side $BC$ at point $F$, and $AB, AC$ at points $E$ and $G$ respectively. If $\frac{AC}{AB}=\frac{3}{4}$, compute $\frac{CF}{BF}$.

Here's what I've done so far:

- Without loss of generality, assume that $AC=3$ and $AB=4$.
- Using the angle bisector theorem, we can let $DC=3x$ and $DB=4x$. This means that to find the ratio $\frac{CF}{BF}$, we need to find $CF$ in terms of $x$.
- If we let $\overline{EF} \cap \overline{AD}=H$, then $\triangle AHF \cong \triangle DHF$ (by SAS)
- After doing some angle bashing, $\triangle EBF \sim \triangle GAF$ and $\triangle EAF \sim \triangle GCF$.

I think what I'm supposed to do here is consider the ratios $\frac{BF}{AF}$ and $\frac{AF}{CF}$, since multiplying them  will yield $\frac{BF}{CF}$, but I'm not sure how to find the value of either of these ratios.[image]

Comment: Using vector methods and a bit of algebra, I get the rather simple and elegant answer $(3/4)^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe that $\triangle ACF \sim\triangle BAF$ (for proof, see comments). From that similarity, we get the proportionality:
$$\frac{CF}{AF} = \frac{AF}{BF} = \frac{AC}{BA} = \frac{3}{4}$$
Multiplying the first two terms gives the wanted result:
$$\frac{CF}{BF} = \frac{CF}{AF}\cdot \frac{AF}{BF} = \left( \frac{3}{4} \right)^2$$
Thus, we get that $\displaystyle\frac{CF}{BF} = \frac{9}{16}$

Comment: The triangles $\triangle ACF \sim\triangle BAF$ have the angle $\hat{F}$ in common.
and:
$$\begin{array}{cl}
\widehat{DAF} &= \widehat{DAC} + \widehat{CAF} \\
\widehat{ADF} &= \widehat{DAB} + \widehat{CAF}\\
\widehat{DBA} + \widehat{DAB} &= \widehat{DAB} + \widehat{CAF} \\
\widehat{DBA} &= \widehat{CAF} \\
\widehat{FBA} &= \widehat{CAF} 
\end{array}$$
Therefore, the two triangles have two equal agnles, thus they are similar.
QED

Answer (score 2):

another approach. Let $X$ be the foot of the external angle bissector of $A$ in $\triangle ABC$ and without loss of generality, let's define $CD = 3 \implies BD = 4$. Now let $x = XC$, then: $$\frac{x}{x+7} = \frac 34 \implies 4x = 3x + 21 \implies x = 21$$

$F$ is the midpoint of $XD$, because of the Apollonius circle.

So $$FD = \frac{21+3}2 = 12 \implies CF = 12-3 = 9, BF = 16 \implies \\\implies \frac{CF}{BF} = \frac{9}{16}$$

Comment: Please edit to explain the notation in the first sentence of your argument.

Comment: is it good now?

Comment: exoteric is different than esoteric. The latter is the word you wanted to use

Comment: You're absolutely right. That was a typo caused by typing on my iPad. :) You got the drift and I'm deleting.

Answer (score 2):

Since, by ASA, $\triangle AHG\cong \triangle AHE$, then supplements $\angle AGF=\angle BEF$ and$$\triangle EBF\sim\triangle GFA$$Thus $\angle EBF=\angle GAF$, and $AF$ is a tangent to the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$, so that $$\frac{CF}{AF}=\frac{AF}{BF}$$Next, join $DG$, $DE$. Since diagonals $EG$, $AD$ are perpendicular bisectors of each other, then in rhombus $AEDG$ $DG\parallel EA$, and hence in $\triangle ABC$,$$\frac{CG}{GA}=\frac{CD}{DB}=\frac{3}{4}$$

[image: CF\BF]
Lastly, since $FH$ bisects $\angle AFD$, then$$\frac{CF}{AF}=\frac{CG}{GA}=\frac{3}{4}$$Therefore$$\frac{CF}{AF}=\frac{AF}{BF}=\frac{3}{4}$$and$$\frac{CF}{BF}=\frac{3^2}{4^2}=\frac{9}{16}$$

Answer (score 2):

Since $AD$ is the bisector of $\angle A$, $\frac{AB}{AC}=\frac{BD}{CD}=\frac{4}{3}, \frac{t+m}{t+n}=\frac{4}{3}$ and $t=3m-4n$

Let $BD=4x,CD=3x,CF=y,AE=AG=t,BE=m,GC=n$

$\frac{CF}{BF}\times \frac{BE}{EA}\times \frac{AG}{GC}=1$, (Menalaus Theorem)

$\frac{BF}{CF}=\frac{BE}{GC}, \frac{7x+y}{y}=\frac{m}{n}$ and $\frac{7x}{y}=\frac{m-n}{n},\frac{x}{y}=\frac{m-n}{7n}$, $\triangle AEG$ is an isosceles with $AE=AG$

Since $\triangle FAD$ is an isosceles and $\triangle AEF \sim \triangle CGF$ then $\frac{AF}{CF}=\frac{AE}{GC}, \frac{3x+y}{y}=\frac{t}{n}$ and $\frac{3x}{y}=\frac{t-n}{n}, \frac{x}{y}=\frac{t-n}{3n}$

then

$\frac{x}{y}=\frac{m-n}{7n}=\frac{t-n}{3n}$ and $7t=3m+4n$

by using $t=3m-4n$ and $7t=3m+4n$, $9m=16n$

Then

$\frac{CF}{BF}=\frac{n}{m}=\frac{9}{16}$